# How to change sequence of attributes of review posted on page magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-review

I want to change sequence of attributes of review . like I want to change position of stars and user name etc like in given picture.
[image: like product and stars are on left side]  and I want the postions of posted attributes likes [image: sequence should be change] . where I can change it and how small clue of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the product review you can override review `list.phtml` in your custom theme. Exact location for product review listing is

`vendor\magento\module-review\view\frontend\templates\product\view\list.phtml`

If you want to override in your custom theme then you can copy this file in your theme with below,

`app\design\frontend\YOURVENDOR\YOUR_THEME_NAME\Magento_Review\templates\product\view\list.phtml`

Comment: where that star rating occurring in code ? and review header ? any idea?

Comment: In the same file you can find all things @Learner

Comment: I dont have file at this path ?  but In vendor . So I have to make just a file named list.phtml and paste in this path or do another things aswell ?

Comment: And for changing position I have to do positing in xml file ?

Comment: you can modify list.phtml as you want @Learner

Comment: last thing , to overide module from vendor I have to copy full module or just a list.phtml file ?

Comment: Just list.phtml :) @Learner

Comment: Can we have chat for few minutes ? I need small help I you dont mind ?@Keyur Shah

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66010/discussion-between-keyur-shah-and-learner).

Comment: you know where its xml file is ? @Keyur Shah